# Status bar blur

Tags: ios, swift

I have `label` inside `scrollView`. I want to blur status bar background when I scrolling and status bar situated above the `label` and text. How to do it?

[image: Example Image]

**UPD**

If I use this code all works fine but my interface freezes. How to fix it?

code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 20{

            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

            blurEffectView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            blurEffectView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
            blurEffectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            blurEffectView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true


            print("fsdjfknsdkfbksjdbfjksdfklsndflknsdlfnlksdfsdfsdf)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check with contentOffset property of scrollview, and the didScoll method of scrollview delegate.

may be you can add blur effect view at top of scrollview and hide or show if the offset is greater than 20 (i.e status bar's height)

**EDIT**

as per code, you are adding each time the scroll view is scrolled so even your scrollview is scrolled by 1 pixel the blur effect view is getting added, just add it once in somewhere didload of view making the instance of blur effect global, and in this provided method (aka didscroll) do hide /show the same. MUST add else condition as well.

Comment: I edit question. It is work but my interface freezing when I start scroll.

Comment: @user please see my edit